# Continous audio play in pages

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, audio

I'm new on Wordpress and I want to add a plugin which it can play audio files, and when I go on another page from the blog, it has to continue the music from where it was paused.
I tried with many plugins, but when I go on another page from my blog, the music starts all over again, when it has to continue from where it left. 
I would appreciate if I can get an answer to that, because this would be the last problem, and then my page would be perfect. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I did this on a site http://www.axjet.co/

I don't know a plugin that will do it, this custom code added to my header.

Using a simple dynamic drive script http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/html5audioplayer.htm

Comment: Isn't your example page a onepager where content is changed by javascript without page reloading? Though content is not loaded correctly it seems there is no page reload. Maybe it's just my smartphone messing it up.

Comment: Sorry yes that site is a one pager but the code I used does work when there is more than one page.

Comment: here is an older site using the same code. http://www.axhornloudspeakers.com/about-us/